# Transform list of objects from response to differnt object Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to convert a response list into a differnt type of object.
Currently make a http call that returns `Observable<Object1>` which i want to convert into `{id: string, type: string} (more info below)`

```
getData(): Observable<Object1[]> {
return this.http.get<Object1[]>(this.url);
}
```

and i invoke this in this fashion:

```
this.getData()
.pipe(
//I understand this can transform each entry into { id: string, type: string } undefined
map(res => res)) 
    .subscribe(res => console.info(res));
```

Object Setup:

```
class Object1 {
name: string;
setId: string;
date: string;
}
```

Any advice how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Transformation would result in following list of objects of type Object2:

```
Object2
{
id: Object1.setId,
type: Object1.name
}
```

JSON response

```
{  
      "name":"Test1",
      "setId":"1",
      "date":"3456" 
   },
   {  
      "name":"Test2",
      "setId":"2",
      "date":"44556"
   }
```

Comment: Can you please add the JSON example of what your getting back from the HTTP call, and what you'd like it transformed to? At the moment it's not clear which fields should be mapping to ID or type

Comment: Object1 to Object2 conversion. Mapping showing in the edit as well as response as requested

Comment: Is it returning an array or a single object?

Comment: your return type is different than the http call `Observable<Object1[]>` . But you are using `this.http.get<Object1>(this.url);`

Comment: Typo, forgot to add [] when writing question. Still not transforming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as it's an array, you will also need to use the array's `map` function as well. This will ensure that each item within the array is being transformed.

You can do the following:

```
this.getData()
    .pipe(
        map(res => res.map(item => ({id: item.setId, type: item.name})))
    ).subscribe(res => console.info(res));
```

Comment: Bingo, just to tweak now :). Thanks